# Quit program without additional messages in do-while loop - Java

Tags: java

my code works for what its supposed to do,

```
do {
    System.out.print("Type a number (or -1 to stop): ");
    
    num = console.nextInt();
    if(num == -1)  
        break;
    
    if (num < min){
        min = num;
    }
    
    if(num > max){
        max = num;
    }
    
} while (true);
System.out.println("Maximum was " + max);
System.out.println("Minimum was " + min);
```

with the exception of when -1 is the first thing input.
if -1 is input with nothing else before the result is this:

```
Type a number (or -1 to stop): -1
Maximum was -2147483648
Minimum was 2147483647
```

when it should be:

```
Type a number (or -1 to stop): -1
```

I don't know how to do it without max and min being printed in every loop, making the code incorrect for general use.

Comment: there are a ton of possible solutions, create a boolean `enteredSomeNumber` that you set inside the loop, add some `numValue` that you increment and then check, etc. You basically need some variable to track that you do not want to output data and then an `if` on that variable.

Comment: Inside the loop, first check for -1, then ``break`` out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it (in terms of the change to your existing code) is just to wrap the `System.out.println` statements in a conditional:

```
if (max >= min) {
  System.out.println("Maximum was " + max);
  System.out.println("Minimum was " + min);
}
```

This works because the condition will only be true if the loop body has executed fully, at least once.

Alternative conditions could include:

- `if (max != Integer.MIN_VALUE)` (or whatever you initialize it to)
- `if (min != Integer.MAX_VALUE)` (ditto initialization)
- `if (min != Integer.MAX_VALUE && max != Integer.MIN_VALUE)`
- Something involving a boolean flag that you set inside the loop when you enter a value other than -1

and many others. But I think just checking that `max >= min` is the neatest.

Comment: Those are the cases where some OP will later read the code and try to reverse engineer the whole thinking and reasoning for that If clause

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a counter to know, that at least one valid input has been given.

```
int counter = 0;
do {
    System.out.print("Type a number (or -1 to stop): ");
    
    num = console.nextInt();
    if(num == -1)  
        break;
    
    if (num < min){
        min = num;
    }
    
    if(num > max){
        max = num;
    }
    counter++;
} while (true);
 if (counter != 0) {
   System.out.println("Maximum was " + max);
   System.out.println("Minimum was " + min);
 }
```

In case counter remains 0, after ending the loop you know that no valid input has been given, therefore you don't print the max, min

Comment: You should explain why this solves the problem, rather than just dumping code.

Comment: It's an admittedly-pedantic error, but this wouldn't work correctly if the user entered a multiple of 2^32 numbers: `counter` could overflow back to zero. You don't actually need the count: just have a boolean that you set to true where you currently increment `counter`.

Comment: @AndyTurner your comment was good and made me curious. So I searched a bit. It seems that after 2^32 -1 inputs the counter will become negative -2147483648. So we actually need about 2^64 inputs to reach 0 again

Comment: the counter will overflow after 2^31-1 inputs (`Integer.MAX_VALUE` - because `int` is signed), and will become -2^31 (`Integer.MAX_VALUE`). There are 2^32 numbers between -2^31 and 2^31-1 inclusively - after all, `int` has 32 bits. And even if it were 2^32-1 and -2^32, that's still only 2^33 inputs before overflow, not 2^64.

Comment: Yes my bad, so it is about 2^31 inputs until we face -2147483648. Then another about 2^31 inputs until we face 0. So 2^31 + 2^31 = 2*2^31 =2^32. I made a mistake with the powers

Answer (score 0):

just add an if for your print conditions :

```
if (min!=-2147483648 && max!=2147483647) {
    System.out.println("Maximum was " + max);
    System.out.println("Minimum was " + min);
}
```

its not the right way but its the fastest i think